# In which shared library .so is "g_signal_connect()" function?

Tags: gtk

I'm GAMBAS programmer on Linux system, and I'm trying to write a very little GTK application by using external GTK+3 functions.

Obviously, I can use these external functions via GTK shared dinamic libraries ".so", particulary: libgtk-3.so.0.1000.8 .

Well, I have a big problem to find  " g_signal_connect() " function, because I cannot identify the exact shared library .so !  :-(

libgtk-3.so.0.1000.8 library doesn't have "g_signal_connect()" symbol.

...where is "g_signal_connect()" function ?  :-(

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add some code formatting...

Answer (score 2):

[`g_signal_connect()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect) is defined as a C preprocessor macro

```
#define g_signal_connect(instance, detailed_signal, c_handler, data) \
    g_signal_connect_data ((instance), (detailed_signal), (c_handler), (data), NULL, (GConnectFlags) 0)
```

where [`g_signal_connect_data()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-data) is the function that's actually in the shared object file.

The macro specifically passes its arguments as the first four arguments to `g_signal_connect_data()`, passes `NULL` as the function to call when the fourth argument is destroyed to indicate that there should be none, and specifies no [special flags](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#GConnectFlags) (0 for the last argument).

You will need to recreate this shortened form yourself in your bindings. How is up to you.

Note that a few other similar functions, like `g_signal_connect_after()`, are the same way. You can see them all in the GLib internal `gobject/gsignal.h` file; on my Ubuntu 14.10 install this is at `/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gsignal.h`.

Comment: This doesn't answer question what shared object provides `g_signal_connect_data` symbol.

Comment: `libgobject-2.0.so` (though on my system they appear to be part of the `.a` file instead?)

Comment: Thank you. I found g_signal_connect_data() function in libgobject-2.0.so library. It works.

Comment: Opssss.... I can see that also libgtk-3.so.0.1000.8 library provides g_signal_connect_data() function !

Comment: Signal functionalities are provided by gobject.

Comment: Yes; I'm not sure why you're seeing that symbol in libgtk.so; it's probably an import from libgobject.so. Use the libgobject.so one instead.